# Linked Files in Visual Studio vs DLL

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a set of .NET code files that I would like to reuse in multiple similar projects. My first inclination would be to create a library, but I have seen some code that makes extensive use of linked files instead. I don't have access to the original developer so I ask here for good reasons or situations in which to prefer linked files vs. a library.

EDIT: By Linked files I mean files added via add-->existing item-->add as link.

Comment: I really don´t know what you mean with LinkedFiles...?

Comment: It works.  But it is murder on source control.  Odds that you can build the project a year from now are not very good.  Not using any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience I don't remember that anybody used Linked Files, because they did not wont to use Shared Projects / Libraries. Usually it was because they need the same code on different platforms, like if you are developing app for Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8. In this case you have two different projects Windows8 and WindowsPhone8. If you have dependency on some API, which is different on these platforms you can hide this under [Preprocessor Directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) and keep all other logic the same in this source code.

If you are writing something, which does not have dependencies on specific platform, but you want to use it on different platforms you can use [Portable Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For example you can keep some logic about how to communicate with Web Services in this library or you can keep some algorithms in here.

If you have the same platform for both apps: it is better to just use dlls for these platforms.

I used both methods with Portable Libraries and Linked Files. There different set of pros and cons for using these approaches. But I definitely did not like my experience with Linked Files. This was so common - when you add some logic (or even new file) in one project and you always need to do the same for second project if you don't want to have build breaks. But usually this means that second project always stop you from verifying work you did for first project. With shared libraries experience was much clear, you just add logic - and if you can compile it - you are good, after this you can change the way how you use this new API in your projects.